# Is it common for interactive unix applications to recognize terminal changes?

Tags: terminal

We all know that resizing is recognized and widely supported, but can every single terminal capability change? Or can the terminal itself be switched?

Comment: An ambiguous question, and the one current answer answers it just one way.  Are you talking about the capabilities simply changing on programs as they run?  Or programs _being notified_ of such changes?

Comment: It is irrelevant how application may recognize that the terminal has changed in any way. This question is asking about what is possible (or allowed) by the OS since at least one such function is known to exist.

Comment: So the answer that you've accepted does not answer the question as you have posed it.

Comment: point.  my answer has been edited to be a bit more explicit about the implications of "serial line".  Hopefully this answers the question as a whole, even if my one-word interpretation differs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

---

Resize is supported by the terminal driver sending the unix signal `SIGWINCH` to the process.  This stands for WINdow size CHange.  The new size can be read from the terminal device.

If you look at the list of unix signals, there is no other such signal for terminal capabilities.

Most terminal capabilities are determined from the environment variable `TERM`.  Since it is an environment variable, `TERM` is not changed by other processes, or by the kernel... The kernel doesn't try to find out what terminal is connected to a serial line.  It doesn't try to find out the terminal size either; that feature is not implemented on the traditional serial line.

Serial lines were designed without an auto-discovery protocol.  EDIT: it is absolutely possible to unplug the terminal and plug in a different one.  The user would have to update their `TERM` manually (as well as the terminal size, `stty rows 24 cols 80`).  The shell, or any other application, would not detect this automatically.

AIUI, the resize feature is not in the POSIX standard.  The relevant `stty` settings are also specifically marked in `man stty` as not being standardized.  However these abilities are presumably shared by all modern systems - fixed character terminals are obsolete.  Most portable programs are written the ncurses library or similar, so the exact signal (and the ioctl to read the size) might vary.

Comment: _Even though_ the questioner has accepted this answer, xe has clarified in question comments that xe is _not_ asking about whether and how programs are notified with signals, but about whether it is simply possible for other terminal settings in addition to the row and column counts, and indeed the terminals themselves, to change.  The correct answer to that is not "No" of course.  (-: